# Chrome failed to start (Protractor, Ubuntu, headless)

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, ubuntu, selenium, protractor

I'm trying to run Chrome with Protractor headlessly on a Ubuntu 13.10 (Atlassian Bamboo) box but Protractor appears to be failing to start Chrome.

I'm using ChromeDriver 2.14, Selenium 2.45, gulp-protractor 0.0.12 (protractor 1.0), here's my output:

```
[05:22:55] Starting 'e2e'...
Using ChromeDriver directly...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
ERROR - Unable to start a WebDriver session.

/mnt/bamboo-ebs/bamboo-agent/build-dir/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:113
  var template = new Error(this.message);
                 ^
UnknownError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Linux 3.11.0-17-generic x86_64)
    at new bot.Error (/mnt/bamboo-ebs/bamboo-agent/build-dir/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/error.js:113:18)
    at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (/mnt/bamboo-ebs/bamboo-agent/build-dir/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/atoms/response.js:106:9)
    at /mnt/bamboo-ebs/bamboo-agent/build-dir/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:152:24
    at /mnt/bamboo-ebs/bamboo-agent/build-dir/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1582:15
    at [object Object].webdriver.promise.ControlFlow.runInNewFrame_ (/mnt/bamboo-ebs/bamboo-agent/build-dir/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1654:20)
    at notify (/mnt/bamboo-ebs/bamboo-agent/build-dir/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:465:12)
    at notifyAll (/mnt/bamboo-ebs/bamboo-agent/build-dir/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:442:7)
    at resolve (/mnt/bamboo-ebs/bamboo-agent/build-dir/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:420:7)
    at fulfill (/mnt/bamboo-ebs/bamboo-agent/build-dir/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:535:5)
    at /mnt/bamboo-ebs/bamboo-agent/build-dir/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1582:15
==== async task ====
WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.acquireSession_ (/mnt/bamboo-ebs/bamboo-agent/build-dir/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:149:22)
    at Function.webdriver.WebDriver.createSession (/mnt/bamboo-ebs/bamboo-agent/build-dir/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:123:30)
    at new Driver (/mnt/bamboo-ebs/bamboo-agent/build-dir/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:477:36)
    at Object.createDriver (/mnt/bamboo-ebs/bamboo-agent/build-dir/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:453:10)
    at DirectDriverProvider.getNewDriver (/mnt/bamboo-ebs/bamboo-agent/build-dir/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/lib/driverProviders/direct.js:68:23)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/mnt/bamboo-ebs/bamboo-agent/build-dir/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:180:37)
    at /mnt/bamboo-ebs/bamboo-agent/build-dir/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/lib/runner.js:257:21
    at _fulfilled (/mnt/bamboo-ebs/bamboo-agent/build-dir/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:797:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/mnt/bamboo-ebs/bamboo-agent/build-dir/node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:826:30)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

Any input is appreciated on this :)

Edit: my protractor config

```
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  // seleniumAddress: 'http://0.0.0.0:4444',
  // add proper version number
  seleniumServerJar: './node_modules/gulp-protractor/node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar',
  specs: ['specs/e2e/dist/*.js'],

  plugins: [{
    path: 'aurelia.protractor.js'
  }],


  // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

Comment: Selenium 2.45 is compatible with chromedriver 2.15 only. One more thing, what is the chrome version? For that selenium it should be at least 41.xx

Comment: runs just fine with 2.14 on OS X @Stanjer and Protractor is choosing the versions, not me :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the difficulties with protractor is that it sits on the top of a large, fragile technology stack, where most components have strict version dependencies on other components.  I would recommend making sure that you are using the latest version of all components, and when you find a configuration that works for you, stop upgrading.

My guess the problem is that you are using protractor 1.0 with a much newer version of selenium and a version of chrome driver that is not compatible.

So:

1. Update to protractor 2.0
2. Use the default selenium driver (ie- remove the `seleniumServerJar` line)
3. run `webdriver-manager update` to ensure the latest chrome driver.

Comment: I cannot get to run tests in chrome, safari, in firefox it works, what could be the reason for that?

Comment: @MatjažJurečič, I need more context. Can you create a separate question for that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030867/timed-out-waiting-for-protractor-to-synchronize-with-the-page-after-11-seconds