# Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronize with the page after 11 seconds - Protractor

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I have a login form, and I want to set input to both inputs, but the test doesn't go through in Chrome, Safari, but with Firefox it works.

Initially I have a $http request and it is done, and as I know, protractor continues when $http is done, so this should not be the issue, or is it?

Error:

> Uncaught exception: Timed out waiting for Protractor to synchronise
>   with the page after 11 seconds. Please see
>   https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md

This is my test:

```js
describe('ADM login page', function () {
 beforeEach(function () {
  browser.get('http://127.0.0.1:8383/v2');
 });

 it('login', function () {
  var username = element(by.css('div.e2e-adm-username-input input.Input-Holder')),
   password = element(by.css('div.e2e-adm-password-input input.Input-Holder'));

  username.sendKeys('test');
  expect(username.getText()).toBe('test');

  password.click();

  password.sendKeys(',,test');
  expect(password.getText()).toBe(',,test');

  element(by.css('div.Login-ActionHolder a.Big-Action')).click();
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add allScriptsTimeout: milliseconds in protractor configuration file. I was having a $http request in the background that was taking too long.

```
exports.config = {
    ...
    allScriptsTimeout: 50000,
    ...
};
```